# Angular: Why does this Signal that relies on another Signal not fire?

Tags: angular

I have three `Signal`s, one that is writable, and two computed signals.

```
  sourceWeapon?: WritableSignal<Weapon<T>>;

  possibleDestinationWeapons: Signal<Set<Weapon<T>>> = computed(() => {
    const destinations = new Set<Weapon<T>>();

    if (this.sourceWeapon !== undefined) {
      destinations.add(this.sourceWeapon());
      this.weaponGraph
        .getWeaponDescendants(this.sourceWeapon())
        .forEach((descendant) => {
          destinations.add(descendant);
        });
    }

    return destinations;
  });

  reachableEdges: Signal<Set<Edge>> = computed(() => {
    const reachableEdges = new Set<Edge>();

    this.possibleDestinationWeapons().forEach((weapon) => {
      console.log(weapon);
    });

    return reachableEdges;
  });
```

For whatever reason, the `possibleDestinationWeapons` `Signal` works as expected, but the `reachableEdges` `Signal` does not seem to fire at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting gotcha'd by [this](https://angular.io/guide/signals#computed-signals-are-both-lazily-evaluated-and-memoized) behavior of signals.

> `doubleCount`'s derivation function does not run to calculate its value until the first time `doubleCount` is read. Once calculated, this value is cached, and future reads of `doubleCount` will return the cached value without recalculating.

Since I was testing this signal before trying to use it in my template, I was not reading it anywhere, which means it was never being evaluated.

Comment: That was going to be my second guess :-) There's lots of little gotchas with signals. Another similar issue is if you'd put it in the template but forgot the `()`. For instance  `<div *ngIf="possibleDestinationWeapons">We have a possible destination weapon</div>` would always show the message but never actually evaluate the computed. I've ended up with some things like this when refactoring (if something previously wasn't a signal).

Answer (score 1):

The way you have the code above you never actually create a `sourceWeapon` signal.
`this.sourceWeapon` is always undefined so the `computed` has no way to know it changed.

Instead you need to create the signal with `undefined` as the initial value:

```
sourceWeapon: WritableSignal<Weapon<T> | undefined> = signal(undefined);
```

Or more simply:

```
sourceWeapon = signal<Weapon<T> | undefined>(undefined);
```

Then when you access it you need to add `()`:

```
if (this.sourceWeapon() !== undefined) {
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified the above code. I don't initialize `sourceWeapon` but it does get assigned a value later when the user clicks on a weapon. Regardless, I did refactor based on your advice because it does seem `Signal`s are designed to always have a value, but my `reachableEdges` signal still does not fire.

Comment: It's ok to initialize it later if you are guaranteed you won't try to access it before it is set. So as the result of a user action probably wouldn't work well.